# Wordpress 4.3 hide admin bar for non administrators

Tags: wordpress, backend

After updating to Wordpress 4.3 users can see the admin bar. I use this code to hide it normally, but this is not working anymore in 4.3.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');

function remove_admin_bar() {
     if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
         show_admin_bar(false);
     }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

The function **current_user_can** refers to capabilities or user role names. So try **manage_options** instead:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');

function remove_admin_bar() {
     // 'manage_options' is a capability assigned only to administrators
     if (!current_user_can('manage_options') && !is_admin()) {
         show_admin_bar(false);
     }
}
```

Instead of using the **after_setup_theme** action you can also add a filter (**prefered for newer WP versions**):

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'handle_admin_bar');

function handle_admin_bar($content) {
     // 'manage_options' is a capability assigned only to administrators
     // here, the check for the admin dashboard is not necessary
     if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Where do you place this code? It should be at the beginning of the **functions.php** of your theme.

Comment: Does the position of this code has effect? I had i before in a separate php files pointed to iit in my functions.php file and that worked. Wil try your solution and come back with the result

Comment: Please see my updated aswer using the **show_admin_bar** filter.

Comment: This worked locally but not on my live site. Do you maby know what can interfere with this code?

Comment: Are the installations identical? I have never observed that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 6 lines code nugget that will remove the admin bar for non contributor users :

```
add_action( 'init', 'fb_remove_admin_bar', 0 );
function fb_remove_admin_bar() {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_posts')) { // you can change the test here depending on what you want
        add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false', PHP_INT_MAX );
    }
}
```

Put that in your function.php file or in your custom plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx all for helping. Eventually the problem was a maintenance plugin. When i disabled this it was working again.

Answer (score 0):

Place the code in your theme's **`functions.php`** file

```
if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
    add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Disable the WordPress Admin Bar Using CSS

You only have to copy and paste the CSS code below in **Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS**, or your style.css file.

The CSS code to disable the toolbar is:

```
#wpadminbar { display:none !important;}
```